# Override default css using Role attribute in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[image]

I have 3 navbars in my page. One of them is displaying in the image given above.
I override the navbar color using role attribute in my css like this

```
.navbar-default[role="transparent_navbar"] 
{

  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;

}
```

Now i want to override the border and background color of 3 line menu also(displaying in given image).
I tried to achieve this by writing the code like this

```
.navbar-default navbar-toggle[role="transparent"] {
  border-color: red;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar[role="transparent"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it's not giving the desired functionality.
Help me in finding out the way to override the 3 line menu design.

Good ideas are welcomed!

Comment: Could you please share the html of your menus?

Comment: @thepio
Oh sorry, i mistyped some html due to which i was facing error.
My css code is right!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean by a "3 line menu design" in your question but this could be your solution:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle[role="transparent"] {
  border-color: red;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle[role="transparent"] .icon-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, i mistyped some html due to which i was facing error.
My css code is right!
Thanks

Comment: sill i am checking your answer.

Comment: Well, glad I was able to help you solve your problem anyways and you were able to find a working solution!

Comment: Yes!
Your code is workin.
Do not worry,I am going to accept your answer :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry, i mistype some html due to which i was facing error. My css code is working fine! Thanks to everyone and sorry